# How to use Retrofit with Rails for Uploading Images to Server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, retrofit

I want to use Retrofit for Uploading Image to server with some Strings. As in Rails the tags are like

```
user[username],user[email],user[password]
```

So after searching a lot i found some where on Github issues of Retrofit to use

```
Call<UploadImageResponse> uploadImage(@Query("user[name]") String username,@Query("user[password]") String password,@Query("user[phoneno]") String phoneno,@Query("user[email]") String email,@Query("user[avatar]\"; filename=\"profilepic.png\" ") RequestBody file);
```

The @Query worked for me. But for image upload using @Query did't worked. I also Tried @Part but not got any success. Can anybody please Help me. I m a Fresher and using this techniques to save time and all the Boiler plate code.

I also Tried the replace in @Query and using @Multipart and @Part with String  upload but it give Internal Server Error. Error 500.

when the Keys were simple like email and password in login then i use Map and pass them in Body

```
@POST("login.json")
Call<Model> model(@Body Map<String,String> user);
```

I hardcodedly pass the Keys and Value in Map and it also worked.

So can any Body please tell me how to Upload Image using Retrofit to server with Key look like

```
user[avatar]
```

in Body.

I can upload image using Postman to server so Server is working Properly.